# Comparing dates from Multiple rows with the same IDs

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
ID        FromDate          ToDate

1         2020-01-01        2020-12-31
1         2021-01-01        2021-12-31
1         2022-03-01        2022-12-31
```

If the difference between "ToDate"  from any row  and FromDate in the subsequent row is less than
30 days then I should get 1 row with FromDate and the second ToDate.

Below is what I would expect to get:

```
ID        FromDate          ToDate
1         2020-01-01        2021-12-31
1         2022-03-01        2022-12-31
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: first which database are you using, second why 2020?

Comment: It's table with UserId's and their membership dates

Comment: the date difference in 2020 it 30 so it will not fit your criteria, also please add the databse , as all have different date functions

Comment: The difference between 2021-12-31 and 2022-03-01 is greater than 30 days hence two rows in the result set.

Comment: Also the database could be any database, it shouldn't matter

Comment: no every rdms has its own function and so it must be declared here.